# Javascript Object Oriented: how to traverse function inside an object?

Tags: javascript, oop

let's say this is my code

```
var myObject = {

    varA: true,
    varB: false,

    init: function() {

        //do something
    },


    doThis: function() {

        //do this

        function doThat(){

           //do that   

        }

    }

}
```

how do i call (if i can) the function  `doThat()` from "outside" the object (like from a  onclick on the page)? is it possible?

i'm working/hacking a piece of code left by a previsous developer and i dont want to rewrite everything from srcatch, so any good workaround is well accepted! thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The function `doThat` is not exposed to any of the outer scopes. Unless you somehow change `doThis` to return a reference to `doThat`, there's no way of calling it besides declaring the function somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this without modifying `myObject`; `doThat` is effectively a private function. There are several ways to work around this, for example making `doThat` a property of `doThis`. This is not recommended, but you *did* say you were hacking.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `doThat` is not a property of `doThis` or of `myObject`. You would have to modify the code to expose the enclosed `doThat` function.

```
var myObj = {
  doThis: function() {
    console.log("doing this");
    return function doThat() { console.log("doing that"); };
  } 
};
```

The above would let you do:

```
myObj.doThis()(); // "doing this" / "doing that"
```